# jasper subreport is not getting printed inside main report

Tags: java, jasper-reports, report, javabeans

i have mainreport and subreport , where main report is getting printed in jasper, but not the subreport, see below code for subreport

```
<jr:list xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd" printOrder="Vertical">
                    <datasetRun subDataset="customerOrderList" uuid="38a2e0f4-ae87-42ad-b3b4-61853d9a2e23">
                        <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($F{customerOrderList})]]></dataSourceExpression>
                    </datasetRun>
                    <jr:listContents height="39" width="590">
                        <frame>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="590" height="39" uuid="609e3e45-03f6-48d0-8776-e6e393d0dbaf"/>
                            <subreport>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="590" height="39" uuid="d4ef2aed-7826-49e5-9bb1-7642cbd01279"/>
                                <subreportExpression><![CDATA["src/main/java/com/crafart/reports/customerOrders.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
                            </subreport>
                        </frame>
                    </jr:listContents>
                </jr:list>
```

i have debugged the code and see there are no issues in generating the report.

i am passing customer order which contains customer details and list of orders. snippet of my customer bean

```
public class Customer {
    private String customerName;
    private List<Order> customerOrderList
}
```

and below code used to generate the report

```
    List<OrderDeclarationBO> orderDeclarationBOLst = new ArrayList<>();
    orderDeclarationBOLst.add(orderDeclarationBO);
    InputStream in = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("order.jrxml");
    InputStream jasperIn = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("order.jasper");
    JasperCompileManager.compileReport(in);
    JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperIn, new HashMap<String, Object>(), new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(orderDeclarationBOLst));
    JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jasperPrint, "orderInvoice.pdf");
```

need help, and dont know what is still required to print subreport.

EDIT :- 
Adding image of the report, where i am getting null values inside sub report, and not aligned properly

[image]

Comment: Are you passing a datasource to your subreport?

Comment: no, i am passing java bean

Comment: What section of your subreport contains the content. If it is the detail section you are not getting any because there is no data source to iterate through.

Comment: i have reffered this link https://ranjitfx.wordpress.com/2010/05/18/subreport-not-displayed-in-main-jasper-report-ireport/ and made empty datasource

Comment: If your content is in the detail section then make sure it is JREmptyDataSource(1) so that there is a row to cause the iteration.

Comment: after adding the empty data source, i am getting two rows, with null values. i have two list. so the data is getting printed , but now it is null

Comment: I guess you are expecting to pass the bean as a parameter. Have you actually got it assigned to the parameter?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76180/discussion-between-pappu-kutty-and-redge).

Comment: I am in chat and waiting for a reply

Comment: you normally need to pass everything that all reports and sub reports need to the master as parameters. You can pass a data source for the subreport as a parameter. These parameters get put in the hash map argument of the fill report method. When invoking a subreport you need to pass any parameters needed by the subreport in from the current report's parameters or from the current row of the current reports datasource.

Comment: @pappu_kutty
I suppose that java-**class** can't find **src**/main/java/com/crafart/reports/customerOrders.jasper.   Move customerOrders.jasper into directory which near classes dir. And see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18656016/jasperreports-cant-locate-subreport

Comment: That was another possibility but I thought @pappu_kutty said he had shown no problems when debugging??

Comment: yeah no issues, it is printing the subreport but all null values

Comment: It seems pappu_kutty  muddle up datasource for list and subreport. List have datasource, but I don't see output fields in list. Subreport haven't dataSource (report output null values). I am don't understand the aim to use list with JRBeanCollectionDataSource($F{customerOrderList} and subreport customerOrders.jasper. Is subreport or list must show customerOrderList?

Comment: @sanBez you got it correct, it was my mistake adding list instead of subreport, i have discovered after reffering to an example, i dont need list in main report, all i need is subreport which will have customerorderlist. the report works now